# Increase layer size while keep the older weights frozen

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, autoencoder

I am now trying to implement the following procedure: at first, I have a trained autoencoder, and then I am thinking of increase the size of the bottleneck layer(increase number of "neurons" in that layer). And then I would like to train the increased model as a whole while keeping the weights corresponding to the older layers frozen.
The overall idea is that, take the MNIST as an example, what features will those new neurons output(What details will these neurons add to the original output)?
My idea to implement this is that first, we train a normal autoencoder, then I can build the same model except the bottleneck layer's size is increased. Then I load the weights to this new model and keep them fixed. But I met 2 problems:

1. How to load weights that only take part of the new weights vector(as the older bottleneck size is smaller than the new one)?
2. How to keep part of the weights fixed? Take keras as an example, it only allows the whole layer to be untrainable(set training=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand from your question you are trying to increase the feature map size or output size in the layers. This can be done by adding a different pipeline at each layer and concatenating both the outputs after the operation. For example

Initially your layer is conv2d(output_layers = a).
So the flow will be Layer-1 -----> conv2d  ---a--> Layer2

Then if you want to have finally a+b  layers then you can add to your code that conv2d(output_layers = b) from the output of layer-1. So that the output will be 'b' feature size from this new convolution and 'a' from initial. Both can be concatenated to get 'a+b' size. The flow will be as follows
Layer-1 ----> concat(conv2d(a)+conv2d(b))---a+b----> Layer2

In this way, you can easily load weights and also understand what the new layers are trying to predict after the training.